# How to make sure oData read in component finishes before Initial View load

Tags: javascript, sapui5

So I have a case where I need to do an odata call in the application's component.js, and based on the response I have to execute certain code on the onInit of the controller. However, when I check the network calls, I see that the call isn't finished completely, which is why I am seeing errors in console, since it tries to access that model, but it hasn't been created since the success handler did not get invoked. Are there any approaches for this?

Comment: Promises, async/await

Comment: But how do I make sure the view doesn't load by default, and only once the success is called, the root view should be initialized?

Comment: Create a promise in your component. Make it accessible via getter. Resolve Promise in success callback. In Controller's onInit do `this.getOwnerComponent().getMyPromise().then(.......)`

Comment: Could you provide any code example, or any sample implementation that I can refer to? Thanks for the help!

Comment: Where are you struggling exactly?

Comment: In component js I have a function fetchFF which returns a promise, and in that Promise I its returning/resolving the odata response inside the success handler. I have one more function getFFPromise, which returns this promise function. And inside the onInit of the controller, I am doing var myPromise = this.getOwnerComponent().getFFPromise. Now I am trying to put my existing code from onInit inside the my myPromise.then(). Am I in the correct path?

Comment: Yes. @Samleijenhorst (answer below) does something similar but without an extra getter for the promise and he doesn't use native Promises.

Comment: Thank you for the suggestions, its working fine by my end, also finally I could see an effective use of Promises. Cheers!

Answer (score 0):

Here is an example:

Component.js:

```
this.promise = $.Deferred()
oDataModel.read("DataSet", {
    success: (oData)=>{
        this.promise.resolve(oData);
    },
    error: (oError)=>{
        this.promise.reject(oError)
    }
});
this.promise.promise();
```

Controller:

```
this.getComponent().promise.then((oData)=>{
    // your code...
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Component.js:

```js
init: function() {
  oDataModel.read("/SET", {
    success: function(oData) {
      // your code before view creation

      // create root view etc
      UIComponent.prototype.init.apply(this, arguments);

      // get your root view and controller if needed
      var oView = this.getRootControl();
      var oController = oView.getController();

      // instantiate router
      this.getRouter().initialize();
    }.bind(this),
    error: function(oError) {
      // error handling
    }
  });

  // code that is not depending on the promise
}
```

Be aware that the root view is created prior to the controller.

Here is the documentation of the [app startup](https://sapui5.hana.ondemand.com/#/topic/d2f58695fce3476f92fdfc07c9e8f7c6)

Comment: My model is set on Manifest, so I would need to use this.getOwnerComponent. However as long as   UIComponent.prototype.init.apply(this, arguments); is not invoked, I cannot make use of this.

Comment: This code snippet is inside the component. Just use this.getModel() and you will get your model.